# Cannot remove grouping in Excel with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

Im strugling with one file that i need to reformat. All i want to do is remove one row, but it seems like because of grouping this file keep throwing errors.

If i run this code on any other file, even with grouping it works flawlessly. But on file that im trying to reformat it gives me "A part with the name '/docProps/core.xml' already exists".

If i remove grouping manually, code runs without problem so i assume this have something to do with grouping. But when i leave file as it is, and do sheet.ungroupRow it dosnt work. Basically no command works on this woorkbook and i dont know why (once again, everything works fine when i remove grouping manually).

If anyone would like i can send them excel file. Thank you in advance for any tips!

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\A677850\\Desktop\\BAM last month\\Pending system restart.xlsx"));

        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
        sheet.removeRow(row);


        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\A677850\\Desktop\\New folder\\Output.xlsx");
        workbook.write(out);
    }}
```

And here is a stack trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: A part with the name '/docProps/core.xml' already exists : Packages shall not contain equivalent part names and package implementers shall neither create nor recognize packages with equivalent part names. [M1.12]
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.addPackagePart(OPCPackage.java:919)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:508)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1488)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:242)
    at WriteUtils.main(WriteUtils.java:400)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The error must come from somewhere else as `/docProps/core.xml` has nothing to do with row grouping. Please show full stack trace of the error.

Comment: Hi Alex, added stack trace as requested. Well im rather convinced it is a grouping or the way this excel sheet is formated because once again it works fine when i remove it manyally. I was also getting "cell index must be >= 0" when using few files in a loop to do the same process.

Comment: The `Pending system restart.xlsx` file seems kind of defect as the core properties are there as package part but relationships of that package part are not properly stored. What happens if you are opening that file in `Excel` amd do nothing else than saving it using `Excel`'s GUI? Is `apache poi` then able proessing that new saved file? If so then try detect where the `Pending system restart.xlsx` comes from. The system which had created this file had done something wrong.

Comment: Hot damn Alex! You where right, it have nothing to do with grouping, it was just my impression. I did what you said and just like that it works! Thank you so much, this is my first post on StackOverflow and already such a pleasent experience thanks to you. Answering your other question, report is created by Microsoft  tool called Report Builder, it is a report done from template so i didn't realy configure anything inside of it.  You already pretty much solved my problem, but just one more question, do you think there is a programmatic way i can do open/save file like i did just now manually?